# Getting knockout computed observables to fire from jQuery slider control

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom knockout binder for the jQuery slider control.  The slider is updating the currentPage observable, but the generic ko.computed that is dependent upon currentPage() never fires.  **Why is this and how can it be fixed so that the generic is fired?**

I found this technique for using async ajax calls with knockout here...[Asynchronous Dependent Observables](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables).  Evidently the `dependentObservable` has been replaced by the `computed`.  I was able to get it to work with `dependentObservable` or with `computed.deferEvaluation=false`, but I need `deferEvaluation=true` so the ajax call isn't fired multiple times.

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/3WN6v/

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin:10px;" data-bind="slider: currentPage, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 10, range: 'min'}"></div>

<div id="plugin" data-bind="template: { name: 'template1', data: $data }" ></div>

<script type="text/html" id="template1">
        <span data-bind="text: displayText"></span>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
// create ko custom binding handler for slider control
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.toJS(allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions) || {};
        $(element).slider(options);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).slider('destroy');
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'slidechange', function (event, ui) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(ui.value);
        });
    }
};

function DataModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(0);
    self.displayText = ko.observable(0);

    ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/json/',
                //data: { page: currentPage() },
                success: function(){
                    self.displayText(currentPage());
                }
            });
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}

dataModel = new DataModel();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually updating the displayText in your slider change event, as the valueAccessor that you are sending in to the binding event is the property that you are binding to the slider, namely, currentPage. Change the signature of the custom binding to include the viewModel, and then use that to update the value of displayText:

```
// create ko custom binding handler for slider control
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = ko.toJS(allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions) || {};
        $(element).slider(options);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).slider('destroy');
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'slidechange', function (event, ui) {
            viewModel.displayText(ui.value);
        });
    }
};
```